# how to draw a line chart in d3 with ordinal scale and some same data

Tags: charts, d3.js

how to draw a line chart with ordinal scale and some same domain data in d3 ? this is a sample demo http://jsfiddle.net/dfang/CPZzV/

here is the data

```
 var scores = [
   {"score":630,"date":"2012-12-22"},
   {"score":680,"date":"2012-12-22"},
   {"score":680,"date":"2012-12-22"},
   {"score":680,"date":"2012-12-23"},
   {"score":1770,"date":"2012-12-24"}
 ];
```

however the chart is not i want , the tick in x-axis is overlapped , i want x-axis is "2012-12-22" , "2012-12-22" , "2012-12-22" .

thanks ! any help will be appreciated !

Comment: are the three values with the same date on purpose?

Comment: still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: @Dan no, maybe the same, maybe not